# Ruby class  object force reload

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-1.9.2

I am trying to reproduce a bug that happens when I get a record from ActiveRecord but the class(the activeRecord class, not the instance) is not in memory, then activeRecord class model is reloaded. I didn't caught the bug since it seems that class object remains in memory for quite some time.

Here is the test:

```
def test_decryption_should_work_at_any_time
    require 'pry'
    binding.pry 
    account = Account.last 
    require 'pry'
    binding.pry
end
```

Take a look and you'll see account is the same object no matter what I try:

```
   102:     f = Account.create!(:key => "secret", :password => "password")
 =>103:     binding.pry 
   104:     account = Account.last 
   105:     binding.pry
   106:   end
   107: end
[1] pry(#<ActiveRecordTest>)> f.class.object_id
=> 70278442281960
```

Then reload the object

```
  104:     account = Account.last 
 =>105:     binding.pry
   106:   end
   107: end
[1] pry(#<ActiveRecordTest>)> account.class.object_id
=> 70278442281960
```

Unfortunatelly the class object is getting the same object for the Account Class than when it was created. Is there a way to force this class to be reloaded?

I know where the bug is, I am just trying to reproduce it. So is there a way to unload that class?

Answer (score 2):

Classes will not be reloaded in production Rails code. That's specifically a feature of Rails' development mode, and even then classes are only reloaded when they need to be, not on each inspection.

Does your `Account` model use STI (single table inheritance)? I've experienced issues like you're mentioning (classes being loaded at runtime in instances like that.